# Hash 64-bit Integer

Tags: java, hash

I have 64-bit positive integers (range from 0 to 2<sup>63</sup> - 1) and I want to hash them into 32-bit positive integers (0 to 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 range).

My data has a **Gaussian** distribution. Can anyone suggest a hash function that will give a low number of collisions for this distribution?

(*Original question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304764/unsigned-64-bit-to-unsigned-32-bit-hash-functions), which I've improved upon.*)

Comment: "less than what" - I want probability to be less. As good as possible. As I have no nice option, any nice hash function for the above will be useful.

Comment: That completely depends on how you expect your incoming values to be distributed within that range.

Comment: `((int) n) ^ ((int) (n >>> 32))` should do it unless there is some reason that bits 32 apart are highly likely to correlate.

Comment: @brimborium, true. But, taking incoming values at random (say gaussian distribution), I want to find the probability of collision.

Comment: If your data is distributed evenly, just forcing the long into and int will do fine. And you'll have a lot of collisions, which mathematically speaking cannot be avoided at that point.

Comment: @alessandro, telling us that you are taking values at random says nothing about the distribution except that the distribution is non-zero at more than one point.

Comment: @alessandro If you are assuming uniform distribution, why don't you just take the last 32 bits, the first 32 bits, every second bit or something like that? Anything that will map evenly will do then...

Comment: @brimborium, "you just take the last 32 bits .." - that will not distribute the input properly, I think.

Comment: @alessandro It will map an equal amount of input values to every output value. If you assume uniform distribution, that will work as good as every other method. I don't suggest this method (or I would have made an answer), I just want to show you that there is nothing better unless you can define your distribution of the input values better...

Comment: @brimborium, It's gaussian distribution

Comment: @Jochen, It's impossible to completely avoid it. But, I want to make it as less as possible. My data follows gaussian distribution.

Comment: @alessandro Now we are getting somewhere. Gaussian around the center (i.e. 2^62-1)? Then we should find a function that has a finer resolution in the middle and less resolution at the borders of the range.

Comment: @alessandro You might want to put that fact (normal distribution) into your question, so everyone can see it... ;)

Comment: @brimborium It's so common for posters to leave out important details in the question, I find you always have to read the comments. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the hash for Long which is a 64-bit integer.

```
int hash = (int) ((l >>> 32) ^ l);
```

BTW: A [gaussian distribution](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gaussian%20distribution) is signed do I don't believe it would appropriate for an unsigned value.

If you have something which follows a guassian distribution which has be scaled and shifted, the lower 32-bit may be still completely random. (Depending on the scale) If the lower 32-bit are random, it doesn't matter what the upper bits are (they can all be 0) and the hash will still be pseudo-random.

BTW: Even if your hash is unique in converting to a 32-bit value, you will have to reduce this further to save memory (Unless you have your own hash table which is 2^32 in size)  This means after reducing the value further to something reasonable e.g. double the size of the number of samples, you will have some collisions (unless it turns out your 64-bit value is far, far more bits than you need)

Comment: How would this decrease the collision probability of normally distributed values?

Comment: @brimborium Normally distributed values are equally likely to be negative as positive and are unbounded. I am not sure how you would apply that to `unsigned long`.

Comment: I think he means normal distribution and there you can scale/shift it to wherever you want...

Comment: @brimborium I suspect you are correct. In which case the lower 32-bits are still likely to be random which is all you need.

Comment: My assumption is that this is some kind of a sensor reading that has 64bit resolution.

Comment: @brimborium That would make sense, except I don't know of anything you can measure in the real world to more than 13 digits of accuracy. (I am sure its possible but I think unlikely)

Comment: You are right. I missed that. It's not perfect, but good enough. It's basically subsampling with factor 2^32...

Comment: Oh you wouldn't believe how many sensors give you overresolution. I have a high frequency signal generator that I can configure to output *10GHz and 1aHz*. Not that I would ever want to check that... :P

Answer (score 3):

You can first map your input data through the (expected) **cummulative** distribution function with the result of having output that then is (expected to be) evenly distributed. You can then put that data into a regular 64-to-32-bit-hash function.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Although histogram equalization is normally a quite expensive task. But that surely minimizes the collision probability.

Comment: True. If it is too expensive, then OP can make it approximate by using some linear approximations, e.g. approximating the expected cummlative distribution with only 5 lines is already quite good.